# Replacing div with div while having few buttons on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div in the middle of html page.
It has 4 links that have images inside and some text.

What I need is this : when a user clicks on one of those links, it completely changes the div ( without reloading the page ), which will have an image, another text and a link. Those 4 links need to stay there, so that user can click on another one and get the same change again.

I couldn't write or find any code that helps me beyond replacing or toggling functions, which are good for 2 elements only.

Here's my HTML markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid fullspan offers_content" id="offers_content">
  <div class="row offers">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_pro_button"/></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_basic_button"/></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qsplus_button"/></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="button_quickstart_offer" class="offer_button" id="offer_qs_button"/></a>          
    </div>  
    <div class="offers_text col-md-7">
      <p> text </p>
    </div>         
  </div>  
</div><!-- /.container-fluid CONTENT--> 

<div class="container-fluid fullspan offers_content" id="offer_1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_pro_button"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_basic_button"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qsplus_button"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qs_button"/></a>          
      </div> 
      <div class="offer_text_ad">
        <img src="images/offer1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive offer_image" />
        <p>text-111</p>
        <a href="pages/Services.htm"> read more </a>
      </div>   
    </div>         
  </div>   
</div><!-- /.container-fluid CONTENT-->  

<div class="container-fluid fullspan offers_content" id="offer_2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_pro_button"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_basic_button"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qsplus_button"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qs_button"/></a>          
      </div> 
      <div class="offer_text_ad">
        <img src="images/offer2.png" alt="" class="img-responsive offer_image" />
        <p>text-222</p>
        <a href="pages/Services.htm"> read more </a>
      </div>   
    </div>         
  </div>  
</div><!-- /.container-fluid CONTENT-->    

<div class="container-fluid fullspan offers_content" id="offer_3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_pro_button" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_basic_button" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qsplus_button" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qs_button" /></a>          
      </div> 
      <div class="offer_text_ad">
        <img src="images/offer3.png" alt="" class="img-responsive offer_image" />
        <p>text-333</p>
        <a href="pages/Services.htm"> read more </a>
      </div>   
    </div>         
  </div>    
</div><!-- /.container-fluid CONTENT-->         

<div class="container-fluid fullspan offers_content" id="offer_4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_pro_button" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_basic_button" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qsplus_button" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="" class="offer_button" id="offer_qs_button" /></a>          
      </div> 
      <div class="offer_text_ad">
        <img src="images/offer4.png" alt="" class="img-responsive offer_image" />
        <p>text-444</p>
        <a href="pages/Services.htm">read more </a>
      </div>   
    </div>         
  </div>  
</div><!-- /.container-fluid CONTENT-->
```

My relevant CSS:

```
.offers_content{
    min-height:450px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#offer_quickstart,#offer_quickstartplus, #offer_basic, #offer_pro{
    display:none;   
}

#offers_content{
    display:block;
}

.offer_image{
    margin: 5% auto auto auto;
}

.offer_text_ad>p{
    color:#000;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "completely changes the div"?

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript and do something along the lines of:

```
function swapDivs(div1, div2) { // where div 1 will disappear and div 2 will take its place
   document.getElementById(div1).className('hidden');
   document.getElementById(div2).className('shown');
}
```

and then CSS like

```
 .hidden {
    top: -500px; // forces div above the screen
 }
 .shown {
 // CSS code for the div you want shown
 }
```

And in the HTML with the link it could be

```
<a onclick="javascript:swap('rowOffers','row');"><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="button_quickstart_offer" class="offer_button" id="offer_qs_button"/></a>
```

Just use "swap('div you want hidden', 'div you want shown')" as you need to.

So the end result will make the first div disappear and the second reappear in its place. So initially code the div you want shown from the beginning set its class to "shown" and then all the other divs as "hidden".

Hopefully this has been helpful and answers your question. If not, feel free to ask anymore about it :)

Comment: Timble, thank you for taking your time to write this. The problem, however, is that I need to be able to switch, say, div4 and div1, then div1 with div3, and there are more than just 2 divs.